# Adding item to array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array, defined as below:

```
String[] letters = {"ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"};
```

How would I go about adding an item to this array?

Comment: You may consider using a `List` instead?

Comment: Just take a look here: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array

Comment: have a look at [this][1]
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2843371/2764279

Comment: Example added with `List`

Answer (score 2):

1.Arrays are fixed in size

2.Before declaring an array we should know the size in advance.

3.We cannot add anything dynamically to an array once we declare its size.

I recommend you to go for collection framework like `List or Set` where you can  increase the size dynamically

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061721/how-can-i-dynamically-add-items-to-a-java-array

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays having static size. One you define the size of a array, it can't grow further dynamically.

Your letters array has a size of 4 element. So, you can't add more element to it.

Use `ArrayList` instead

```
List<String> letters = new ArrayList(); // Java 7 and upper versions
letters.add("ab");
letters.add("cd");
....// You can add more elements here
```

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas : Check updated answer with example

Comment: Downvoter: Please specify the reason for that.

Comment: Seeing the list of duplicates of this question, I think the reason for the downvote is pretty clear. There's absolutely no need to have another copy with the same answers and examples on SO.

Comment: @SvenT23 : It can't be done by closing the question instead. That's the recommended way of doing.

Comment: I thought the recommended way of doing things was referring to the duplicate with the flag to close it, not answering the question again :) According to my knowledge, that solves her problem and gets rid of this copy faster.

Answer (score 1):

By using this type of array initialization you **cannot** simply add more elements.

```
String[] letters = {"ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"};
```

Could be paraphrased as:

```
String[] letters = new String[4];
letters[0] = "ab";
letters[1] = "cd"; 
letters[2] = "ef";
letters[3] = "gh";
```

So, your array's length is only 4. 
To add more elements you should somehow copy you array to a bigger one and add elements there. Or just use ArrayList which does the hard work for you when capacity is exceeded.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible without a workaround
like http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-append-values-into-an-object-array/

try ArrayList, List, Map, HashMap or something like this instead