# Null pointer exception Java 2d String

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

So I have a string[][] where I want to save some information from my database. Eclipse told me I needed to initialize my string[][], so i said string[]][] = null. Now I get a null pointer exception, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String systems[][] = null;
            int firstcounter = 0;

            String item = "SELECT ram, cpu, mainboard, cases, gfx FROM computer_system";

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(item);
            while (rs.next()){
                systems[firstcounter][0] = rs.getString("ram");
                systems[firstcounter][1] = rs.getString("cpu");
                systems[firstcounter][2] = rs.getString("mainboard");
                systems[firstcounter][3] = rs.getString("cases");
                systems[firstcounter][4] = rs.getString("gfx");
                firstcounter++;
            }
            System.out.println(systems[0][0]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How can I dynamically add items to a Java array: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5061721/1023562

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supposed to initialize the array to a non null value in order do use it :

```
String systems[][] = new String[n][5];
```

where `n` is the max capacity of the array.

If you don't know in advance how many rows your array should contain, you can use an `ArrayList<String[]>` instead, since the capacity of an `ArrayList` can grow.

For example:

```
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        List<String[]> systems = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String item = "SELECT ram, cpu, mainboard, cases, gfx FROM computer_system";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(item);
        while (rs.next()){
            String[] row = new String[5];
            row[0] = rs.getString("ram");
            row[1] = rs.getString("cpu");
            row[2] = rs.getString("mainboard");
            row[3] = rs.getString("cases");
            row[4] = rs.getString("gfx");
            systems.add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because, you initialize the `systems[][]` as `null`.

Try `String systems[][] = new String[x][y];` instead, where x and y is the dimensions of your matrix.

But we do not like arrays in Java code, use [Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead. Lists can expand dinamically, while your matrix can't, and Lists provide compile time type check, so it is more safe to use. For more info see **Item 25** from Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), which says:

> Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays

Comment: Why [5][10] ? :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize in following way

```
String systems[][] = new String[size][size];
```

where size = size of the string array you want.