# Send mail to email of users saved in database

Tags: java, oracle

I am able to send email on a particular email id, but now I want to retrieve email ids of multiple users from a database and send them a message. I have tried several ways but I'm unable to get the desired results.

Here is my original code:

```
<%@page import="oracle.net.aso.i"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<%!
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
%>
<%
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","rahul","odeya");
st=con.createStatement();
rs=st.executeQuery("select email from register");
%>
<%
String host="", user="", pass="";
int i=0;
String id[] = new String[100];
while(rs.next())
{
    id[i] = rs.getString(1);
}
host ="smtp.gmail.com"; 
user ="ocrsindore@gmail.com"; 
pass ="odeya";

String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

String from ="ocrsindore@gmail.com"; 

String subject =request.getParameter("subject");

String messageText =request.getParameter("message");

boolean sessionDebug = true;

Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol.", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(id[i])};

msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setContent(messageText, "text/html"); 

Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host,from,pass);
try {
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

out.println("message successfully sended"); 
}
catch (Exception err) {

out.println("message not successfully sended"); 
}
transport.close();
%>
<jsp:include page="adminis.html"/>
```

Comment: What i understand from your question is CHECK if a new message in databse arrive or not? is that what you want?

Comment: if my answer helped you, can you please mark it as accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems :

1. First off, your `i` never gets incremented. You need to add `i++;` at the end of your loop. The way you are doing now, you are looping over all results of your database query, but always saving in `id[0]`.
2. Also, replace `rs.getString(1)` by `rs.getString(0)`. That's because `email` is column 0 of your database query results, not 1.
3. Finally, in your code, when you collect email addresses at the end, you capture only one, because you don't loop on `i`. You should loop on your `id` array, and create an `InternetAddress` object for each email.

Overall, what you need to do is to replace your while loop by :

```
while(rs.next())
{
   id[i] = rs.getString(0);
   i++;
}
```

and replace `InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(id[i])};` by :

```
InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[id.length];
for(int i=0; i<id.length; i++){
   address[i] = new InternetAddress[id[i]];
}
```

That said, it should work. Now, a few comments about your code :

- why initialize `id` with length 100 ? If you do that, you won't be able to handle a case with more than 100 email addresses. You probably need to use an ArrayList instead of an array. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061721/how-can-i-dynamically-add-items-to-a-java-array)
- anyway, there is a simpler solution, to transfer a `ResultSet` to an array, simply use `ResultSet`'s [`getArray` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray(java.lang.String))
- you don't need to add any `%><%` like this :

  ```
  %>
  <%
  ```

  This is useless
- some indentation could make your code clearer and easier to understand, for you and your readers.
- no need to declare `host`, `user`, and `pass`, as empty, only to fill them a few lines later

Overall, if you implement these comments and the important changes, your code would look like this :

```
<%@page import="oracle.net.aso.i"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<%!
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "rahul", "odeya");
st = con.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("select email from register");

String[] id = rs.getArray("email");

String host ="smtp.gmail.com"; 
String user ="ocrsindore@gmail.com"; 
String pass ="odeya";

String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

String from ="ocrsindore@gmail.com"; 

String subject = request.getParameter("subject");

String messageText = request.getParameter("message");

boolean sessionDebug = true;

Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol.", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[id.length];
for(int i=0; i<id.length; i++){
   address[i] = new InternetAddress[id[i]];
}

msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setContent(messageText, "text/html"); 

Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, from, pass);
try {
   transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
   out.println("message successfully sent"); 
}
catch (Exception err) {
   out.println("message send failed"); 
}
transport.close();
%>
<jsp:include page="adminis.html"/>
```